# How to retrieve multiple datasets per page via scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract all 50 datasets from a search result page with the help of scrapy.

Originally I used to retrieve each dataset from product pages, in order to go easy on the scraped page I came up with the idea to get all data I need just from the search result page instead, as there is all the data I need within the product page snippets. So multiple result sets on each page instead of a single one.

My code does count the amount of datasets and then should cycle through the datasets in order to extract the data.

e.g.

```
# how many datasets on this page?
datasets = len(response.xpath('//div[@class="col-result-list"]'))
```

Now cycle through all the elements:

```
for i in range(0, datasets):
    print('dataset_' + str(i))
    # new dataset
    mouse                  = mouseItem()
    mouse['i02_title']     = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-result-list"][' + str(i) + ']/div[@class="result-list-entry"]/text()').extract_first()

return mouse
```

Unfortunately this does not work as expected. The function just returns 1 dataset and I suppose this is because I am returning the object too early or at the wrong point.

This is the entire class:

```
class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test'

    allowed_domains = ['www.test.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.test.com/all-from-category/']

    rules = (

        # parse this pages
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=['.*test\.com\/all\-from\-category\/\?resultsPerPage=100\&pageNumber=(\d.*)&\$cat=nvkps23f7dy']), 
            callback='parse_item'
        ),

        # follow all the index urls 
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(allow=['.*test\.com\/all\-from\-category\/\?resultsPerPage=100\&pageNumber=(\d.*)&\$cat=nvkps23f7dy']), 
            follow=True
        ),
    )


    def parse_item(self, response):

        # how many datasets on this page?
        datasets = len(response.xpath('//div[@class="col-result-list"]'))

        print("Amount of data sets:" + str(datasets))

        # get the individual datasets 
        for i in range(0, datasets):
            print('dataset_' + str(i))
            # new dataset
            mouse                  = mouseItem()

            mouse['i02_title']     = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-result-list"][' + str(i) + ']/div[@class="result-list-entry"]/div[@class="result-list-entry-data"]/div[@class="result-list-entry-title"]/a/text()').extract_first()


        return mouse
```

How can I alter my code in order to retrieve all datasets from one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `parse_item` method you just return last item that processed in the for loop.
to get all of them your `parse_item` method have to be something like this:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    # how many datasets on this page?
    datasets = len(response.xpath('//div[@class="col-result-list"]'))
    print("Amount of data sets:" + str(datasets))

    # get the individual datasets
    for i in range(0, datasets):
        print('dataset_' + str(i))
        # new dataset
        mouse = mouseItem()

        mouse['i02_title'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="col-result-list"][' + str(
            i) + ']/div[@class="result-list-entry"]/div[@class="result-list-entry-data"]/div[@class="result-list-entry-title"]/a/text()').extract_first()

        yield mouse
```

I just removed `return statement` and add `yield statement` at last the of for loop.